# flutter toggle a state with provider state management flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying to implement a provider to render between different widget when the state changes.

Here, I have defined a function called `toggleContainer()` in the provider controller.

```
class UserNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  toggleContainer() {
    bool isExpanded = false;
    if (isExpanded == false) {
      isExpanded = true;
    } else {
      isExpanded = false;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then, in the app I declared the `useNofifier` as below and also implement the function

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserNotifier userNotifier = Provider.of<UserNotifier>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only( ...

           GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                userNotifier.toggleContainer();
              },
              child: Container(
                child: userNotifier.isEpanded ? Text("close") : Text('open'), //isExpanded is undifened
              ),
            ),
```

So now, I don't the proper implementation and the `isEpanded` returns undefined.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserNotifier()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue is coming because `isExpanded` is inside `toggleContainer()`. It will be on class level.

```dart
class UserNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  toggleContainer() { 
    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Next issue is typo, it will be `child: userNotifier.isExpanded`.

But it will be recommended to use `Consumer` widget in this case

```dart
Consumer<UserNotifier>(
  builder: (context, value, child) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        value.toggleContainer();
      },
      child: Container(
        child: value.isExpanded
            ? const Text("close")
            : const Text('open'), //isExpanded is undifened
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: You can check [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/) to learn more about provider.

Comment: okay, thanks for you help